# Carbon dating using exponential function

Tags: algebra-precalculus, physics, chemistry

Basic carbon dating problems I've seen before, but this seems to take more details into account, both in model and the questions, which I have not seen before, nor understand. Anyone that can help me?

**Problem:**

Carbon consist of the stable isotope ${}^{12}$C and the unstable isotope ${}^{14}$C that have a half-time of 5730 years. Any other isotopes are assumed non-existing. The relationship between ${}^{14}$C and ${}^{12}$C in living material is $1.5\cdot10^{-12}$. 1 mol is $6\cdot10^{23}$ particles and ${}^{12}$C weighs 12 grams/mol and ${}^{14}$C about 14 grams/mol.

**A.** An item was said to be from year 400. ${}^{14}$C measurement in 1977 showed 6.08 decays/gram/year. From what year is this item?

**B.** An piece of char cole had 4.09 decays/gram/year. Living material had 6.68. When was the char cole made?

**C.** In skeleton residue the proportion ${}^{14}$C/${}^{12}$C was found to be 6.24% of what it is in living material. When did the person live.

**My work (so far):**

**A.** Let $N_{14}(t)=N_{14}(0)\cdot2^{-t/5730}$ denote the number of ${}^{14}$C particles before decay starts. Assume 1 gram material from the item. It consists of $N_{12}(0)$ ${}^{12}$C particles and $N_{14}(0)$ ${}^{14}$C particles. We have a total of
$$
N_{12}(0)+N_{14}(0)
$$
${}^{12}$C and ${}^{14}$C particles.

Divide by $6\cdot10^{23}$ particles/mol and we get
$$
\frac{N_{12}(0)}{6\cdot10^{23}}+\frac{N_{14}(0)}{6\cdot10^{23}}
$$
mol and multiply by 12 and 14 g/mol we get
$$
12\cdot\frac{N_{12}(0)}{6\cdot10^{23}}+14\cdot\frac{N_{14}(0)}{6\cdot10^{23}}
$$
grams which should equal 1, i.e.
$$
12\cdot\frac{N_{12}(0)}{6\cdot10^{23}}+14\cdot\frac{N_{14}(0)}{6\cdot10^{23}}=1
\quad\Leftrightarrow\quad
12\cdot\frac{\frac{N_{14}(0)}{1.5\cdot10^{-12}}}{6\cdot10^{23}}+14\cdot\frac{N_{14}(0)}{6\cdot10^{23}}=1
$$
since
$$
\frac{N_{14}(0)}{N_{12}(0)}=1.5\cdot10^{-12}
\quad\Leftrightarrow\quad
N_{12}(0)=\frac{N_{14}(0)}{1.5\cdot10^{-12}}.
$$

This gives
$$
N_{14}(0)=7.5\cdot10^{10}
$$
${}^{14}$C particles. Hence
$$
N_{14}(t)
=N_{14}(0)\cdot2^{-t/5730}
=7.5\cdot10^{10}\cdot2^{-t/5730}
$$

If this is even correct calculations, I don't know how to continue. Any thoughts?

Comment: The ratio $1.5\times10^{-12}$ strikes me as too small. Are you sure that is correct, or measured in the same units of C-14 and C-12?

Comment: I'm not sure about much in this text. I copied it from the book but your calculation of 113,000 years seems far off from the answer 'year 1275'. I sadly have no idea what the authors means with the text or how they expect it to be solved. I've seen the number $10^{-12}$ in some other post about carbon dating. Personally I have no clue what is correct values.

Comment: I withdraw my comment. Reference pages do seem to say that is the ratio. For some reason I thought it was higher.

Answer (score 1):

Edit: you are using the currently understood value of 5730 for the half-life. [Apparently](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Radiocarbon_dating) it was once accepted that the half-life is 5568 years. This resource is probably an older one that is using that value. I will edit my answer below to reflect this.

---

Assume there is one gram of carbon in front of you, almost all of which is $^{12}\mathrm{C}$. Back when the material was alive, it was also one gram of $^{12}\mathrm{C}$. The amounts of $^{14}\mathrm{C}$ are so small to not yet be relevant to the calculation.

So with one gram of $^{12}\mathrm{C}$, there was $\frac{1}{12}$ of a mole of $^{12}\mathrm{C}$. So there were about $\frac{1}{12}\times6\mathrm{E}23=5\mathrm{E}22$ atoms of $^{12}\mathrm{C}$.

The $1.5\mathrm{E}{-12}$ ratio is a ratio of atoms of $^{14}\mathrm{C}$ to atoms of $^{12}\mathrm{C}$. Therefore when the material was alive, there were $5\mathrm{E}22\times 1.5\mathrm{E}{-12}=7.5\mathrm{E}10$ atoms of $^{14}\mathrm{C}$.

So the $^{14}\mathrm{C}$ atom count function over time is $7.5\mathrm{E}10\left(\frac12\right)^{-t/5568}$. Its derivative is about $-9.337\mathrm{E}6\left(\frac12\right)^{-t/5568}$, in lost atoms per year. But part (A) says you are currently losing $6.08$ atoms per year (from your one gram sample). So
$$\begin{align}
-9.337\mathrm{E}6\left(\frac12\right)^{-t/5568}&\approx-6.08\\
\left(\frac12\right)^{-t/5568}&\approx6.512\mathrm{E}{-7}\\
\frac{t}{5568}&\approx20.55\\
t&\approx114424
\end{align}$$

This says the material is over 114 thousand years old. That's pretty far off from the suggested age in part (A). And I think carbon dating is not supposed to be usable/reliable beyond something like 50,000 years into the past.

In a comment, you say the age should really come out to 702 years (from 1275 to 1977). If that were the case, the current absolute loss rate of atoms would work out to be $1.019\mathrm{E}7$ atoms per gram per year, far more than $6.08$. I suspect something is misprinted somewhere.

---

Parts (B) and (C) seem a lot easier. For (B), solve $\left(\frac12\right)^{-t/5568}=\frac{4.09}{6.68}$. For part (C), solve $\left(\frac12\right)^{-t/5568}=0.0624$

Comment: The text book seems to have some very picky model in mind since they have the following answers (that I cannot work out): A. year 1275, B. 3940 years ago, C. 22285 years ago. Anyone that can figure out how they arrive at these numbers?

Comment: The latter two answers are consistent with a half-life of 5568 years. You can see [here](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Radiocarbon_dating) that the half-life was once accepted to be 5568 years, and has since been re-measured to 5730 years.

Comment: I've revised my answer some. But I think the "6.08 decays/gram/year" stated in part (a) must be some kind of misprint. The material you have will be on the order of grams, not thousands of kilograms. So you have some substance that is supposedly losing on the order of 6 atoms of C-14 per year, with 6 beta decays over the course of the year. How could you ever detect that with real detection devices? So I think this value needs to be orders of magnitude larger to make sense.